# Convert vector<map<char, set<int>>> to vector<map<int, set<char>>>

Tags: c++, vector

I have a c++ code that contains a collection of vectors v1 in the format: `vector<map<char,set< int>>>` and I want to convert it into another collection of vectors v2 of the format: `vector<map<int,set< char>>>`

For example:

```
v1= [{'a', {1,2,3,}}, {'b', {1,2}, {'c', {1,3}}]
```

to be converted into:

```
v2= [{1, {'a','b','c'}}, {2, {'a','b'}}, {3, {'a','c'}}]
```

So far, I created a function to create the first vector (randomly), but I want to change that set of vectors into the format vector of maps of characters and set of integers.

```
void get_keylocker(char TxnId, vector<map<char, set<int>>> * v_KeyLocker){
    set<uint64_t> setK;
    map<char, set<int>> mapK;
    int r = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        r = rand()%(20-10 + 1) + 10;
        setK.insert(r);
    }
    mapK.insert(pair<char, set<int>>(TxnId, setK));
    v_KeyLocker->push_back(mapK);
}

void get_txnLocker(vector<map<char, set<int>>> * v_KeyLocker, vector<map<int, set<char>>> * v_TxnLocker){
    ...
}

int main(){
    vector<map<char, set<int>>> v_KeyLocker;
    vector<map<int, set<char>>> v_TxnLocker;
    for (char r ='a'; j<'g'; j++){
        getkeys(r, &v_KeyLocker);
    }

    get_txnLocker(&v_KeyLocker, &v_TxnLocker);

    return 0;
}
```

I'll be grateful if you have any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Use a hardcoded `v1` while you test out your conversion.

Comment: The second vector appears to contain exactly as many elements as there are distinct `int` values. Do you really want a vector of maps holding one key each (which seems rather pointless), or just a single map with multiple keys? Or something else, and I misunderstood your example?

Comment: What's `getkeys`, and how, if at all, is it related to `get_keylocker`? What's `j`, and how, if at all, is it related to `r`?

Comment: `get_keylocker` always generates a map with exactly one element. But your example appears to show a map with two elements: `{'b', {1,2}, {'c', {1,3}}` Is it produced by some code not shown?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is just an example. The code generates a map of a char and a set of integers and push them into the vector. Through the loop more maps will be added. The example at the top is just a simple illustration of what exactly needed.

Comment: Why do you need a vector of maps for that, and not just a single map? A map can contain multiple key/value pairs, you know.

Comment: Maybe I should put it this way: assume the first set of vectors as: (house A is painted with colors white, black and blue, house B is painted with white and black, and house C is painted with white and blue. So the second vector should be like: white is used to paint houses A, B and C, black is used to paint houses A and B, while blue is used to paint houses A and C. Assume also that I'm stuck with the first vector as an input and I need to create vector v2 out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines (not tested):

```
void get_txnLocker(vector<map<char, set<int>>> * v_KeyLocker,
                   vector<map<int, set<char>>> * v_TxnLocker){
  map<int, set<char>> translated;
  for (const auto& m : *v_KeyLocker) {
    for (const auto& elem : m) {
       for (int key : elem.second()) {
         translated[key].insert(elem.first);
       }
    }
  }

  for (auto& elem : translated) {
    v_TxnLocker->emplace_back();
    v_TxnLocker.back()[elem.first].swap(elem.second);
  }
}
```